# Hide/show items in a data bound listview, by setting a property directly in the list item

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, attached-properties

This has been bugging me for a really long time. So I have a ListView which displays a Custom Usercontrol (custom control) in its ItemsControl datatemplate. So basically, the list items are stored in a control which has its own ViewModel, separate from the ListView ViewModel. My custom control has a text and a button. Clicking on the custom control’s button would display a list specific to that control (this part works fine). What I’ll like to achieve is the ability to click the custom control’s button, and hide every other item in the listview (Parent) , and click the same button to restore visibility to the other items.

Just setting the visibility of the custom control in the DataTemplate won’t work, because I want to set the visibility directly from the Button click event in the Custom control.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add a field in the class that is type Visibility and bind the items visibility to that field, and then when you click the button, set the field to show/hide as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have a control you want to change visibility on, so lets bind it to a field in our class called IsVisible.

```
<Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Content="Hide Stuff" Command="{Binding HideStuffCommand}"></Button>
    <ListView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="Collapsed">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="Visible">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

We are using this class:

```
public class Person: ViewModelBase
{
    private int _Id;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return _Id; }
        set { this.Set(ref _Id, value); }
    }

    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { this.Set(ref _Name, value); }
    }

    private Visibility _IsVisible;
    public Visibility IsVisible
    {
        get { return _IsVisible; }
        set { this.Set(ref _IsVisible, value); }
    }

    public Person(int id, string name)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.IsVisible = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

I am using MVVM Light, so the this.Set handles the raise property changed.

Now your click event:

```
public RelayCommand HideStuffCommand { get; private set; }
    public void HideStuff()
    {
        foreach (var t in People)
        {
            if (t.Id % 2 == 0)
            {
                t.IsVisible = t.IsVisible == Visibility.Visible ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
    }
```

and in your viewmodel constructor:

```
People = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
            People.Add(new Person(1, "Fred"));
            People.Add(new Person(2, "Wilma"));
            People.Add(new Person(3, "Barney"));
            People.Add(new Person(4, "Betty"));

            this.HideStuffCommand = new RelayCommand(HideStuff);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this information. But this isn’t what I’m looking for. I know how to bind visibility to a view model. What I’m having trouble with is clicking on a listview item and hiding every other item in the list. Clicking again should restore every other item in the list.

Comment: Ok, here's the complete code, still using binding, this hides every other item in the list using mod 2 (or you can change it to whatever item you set the visibility on..)